# How to determine the sum of function series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm confused about the sum of this function series: $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }1/2\, \left( -1 \right) ^{n}{{\it nx}}^{n}$
I found out the Radius of Convergence: $\left| x \right| <1$
I found the derivative but that only made things worse.
So how do I determine the sum of this series?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \; \frac{(-1)^n n x^n}{2}$.  You have found that this series, a Taylor series expanded around $x=0$, has radius of convergence $1$.

This would be easier to recognize if we could make that factor of $n$ in the summand go away.  One way to do this is to integrate.  Now $\int x^n \mathrm{d}x = \frac{n^{n+1}}{n+1}$, so it would be "cleaner" to move one copy of $x$ out of the sum.  (When you first do these sorts of manipulations, it is not easy to see that such small changes help.  With practice, you can see where the computation is going and make these small changes to end up at a nicer place.)  We use that a power series can be integrated on its disk of convergence termwise.  We compute \begin{align*}
\int \frac{f(x)}{x} \, \mathrm{d} x &= \int \; \sum_{n=1}^\infty \; \frac{(-1)^n n x^{n-1}}{2} \, \mathrm{d}x  \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \; \frac{(-1)^n}{2} \int \; n x^{n-1} \, \mathrm{d}x  \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \; \frac{(-1)^n}{2} x^{n}  \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \; (-1)^n x^{n}  \\
&= \frac{1/2}{1+x}  \text{.}
\end{align*}

So now we know (on its disk of convergence) \begin{align*}
f(x) &= x \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \frac{1/2}{1+x}  \\
&= \frac{-x}{2(x+1)^2}  \text{.} 
\end{align*}

(You might be concerned about the "$+C$".  If you look closely that the operation that was actually performed
$$  f(x) = x \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \int \sum \dots  \text{,}  $$
you'll see that the ambiguity in choice of antiderivative was eliminated by the subsequent differentiation.  Equivalently, you'll see that we used the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus with the integration and differentiation operations in the order that yields an identity.)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** start with
$$f(x) = \sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n x^{n}$$